# How to define possibly undefined type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the best way to define a possibly undefined interface? What i have is this. I'm looking for an alternative. Something more elegant and concise if possible.

```
interface RouteInterface {
  path: string;
  test: boolean;
}
type TypeOrUndefined<T> = T | undefined;
```

This is how i'm using it:

```
const returnObj: TypeOrUndefined<RouteInterface> = 
  redirectChoices.find(
    (option: RouteInterface) => option.test
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally and personally I do it like this:

```
const returnObj: RouteInterface | undefined = 
  redirectChoices.find(
    (option: RouteInterface) => option.test
  );
```

Also this particular code could be written just like this:

```
const returnObj = 
  redirectChoices.find(
    (option: RouteInterface) => option.test
  );
```

`returnObj` is still `RouteInterface | undefined` since `Array.prototype.find` returns a union with `undefined` included.